# Cacke Key components - Akamai

Tags: cdn, akamai

I am trying to replicate Akamai CDN rules on a different CDN. Not able to find what are the default components of cache key on Akamai, are all the HTTP headers and Cookies included by default? or are cookies and other HTTP headers included in the cache key only if they are explicitly specified?

Answer (score 1):

No, cache-keys do not contain header or cookie information by default. They will have to be explicitly added using **Cache-ID Modification** behavior. The default cache-key has the following details on them

1. Akamai proprietary information (such as CP Codes)
2. Cache TTL
3. Hostname (Origin or Incoming Host header)
4. URL Path

Answer (score 0):

The cache key of your content can be learned by using the [Akamai Pragma Headers](https://myakamai.force.com/customers/s/article/Using-Akamai-Pragma-headers-to-investigate-or-troubleshoot-Akamai-content-delivery?language=en_US).

You want to send (at a minimum) the `Pragma: akamai-x-get-true-cache-key` header to see the response from Akamai showing what is used to create your cache key.